# Check Box not returning correct value

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using checkboxes for my computer science project, I have seen countless youtube videos and tutorials, however the value of my checkbox is alwasy returning zero. Can anyone please help me?

```
x=IntVar()
def display():
    if x.get()==1:
        print('HI')
    else:
        print('Not hi')
                    check_button=Checkbutton(check_new,text='Spa',variable=x,onvalue=1,offvalue=0,command=display)
                    check_button.pack()
                    myButton=Button(check_new,text='SHow selection' )
```

I was expecting the value to return 1, however it is alwas returning 0

Comment: The code _seems_ ok (besides the indentation) but is lacking too much to be sure. Please create a [mre].

Comment: The `Checkbutton` and `Button` widgets should be outside of `display()` function.